# Probability, need help on two Random Variable

Tags: probability, random-variables

I have a question about computing the probability of two random variable.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent random variable with distribution $f_x$ and $f_y$ such that they are only define for $x>0$ and $y>0$, respectively. Let c be a constant.

If to compute the $\Pr\{c< X< Y\}$,

do I just integrate
$$
P=\int_{x=c}^{+\infty} \int_{y=0}^x f_y*f_x \, dy \, dx
$$

Comment: no. $Y$ must be greater than $X$. so you integrate $y$ from $x$ to infinity.

Comment: @symplectomorphic, can you please elaborate

Comment: You need to integrate $f_X(x)f_Y(y)$ over the region $\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2 : c<x<y\}$. You have not done that correctly: your region has $y$-values which are between $0$ and $x$, when the $y$ values *should* be between $x$ and $+\infty$. So change the limits in the inner integral to reflect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compute the Pr{c< X< Y} you should calculate for each x > c the probability of y > x and then integrate all that probabilities. That gives you the integral:

$$
P=\int_{c}^{+\infty}f_x dx\int_{x}^{+\infty}f_ydy
$$